# Number inside parentheses by app in app bar

Tags: google-chrome

What does the number in parentheses beside the Facebook app in the app bar of Google Chrome signify?

Answer (score 1):

It is the number of notifications that you have.

If you go to the full Facebook page, it is the number on a red background in the top right.